# heroku php nginx stack - using composer and foreman for local instance

Tags: php, heroku, nginx, composer-php

my dev env is linux and im trying to figure out the new heroku php tools explained [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings)

I installed nginx 1.6 and php 5.5.11 on my system , configd nginx for php5-fpm and that works. I can serve a page with phpinfo() in it.

env detls:

> PHP 5.5.11-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Apr 23 2014
>   12:31:47)

My problem is running composer install and then foreman in the php project directory so that i can have local env that will reliably be an image of what will eventually run on heroku.

```
composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction
```

above runs ok and puts all the symlinks in the the "vendor/bin" directory in the project.

i did not change any of the config files created by the above.

foreman check is OK

when i run foreman start , i get the issues below:

```
14:30:39 web.1  | Using PHP-FPM configuration file 'vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/php/php-fpm.conf'
14:30:39 web.1  | Using PHP configuration (php.ini) file 'vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/php/php.ini'
14:30:39 web.1  | Using Nginx server-level configuration include 'vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/nginx/default_include.conf'
14:30:39 web.1  | Using Nginx configuration file 'vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/nginx/heroku.conf.php'
14:30:39 web.1  | Interpreting vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/nginx/heroku.conf.php to heroku.conf
14:30:39 web.1  | Starting log redirection...
14:30:39 web.1  | Starting php-fpm...
14:30:39 web.1  | Starting nginx...
14:30:39 web.1  | vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx: line 183: php-fpm: command not found
14:30:41 web.1  | nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
14:30:41 web.1  | 2014/05/05 14:30:41 [warn] 25269#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
14:30:41 web.1  | 2014/05/05 14:30:41 [emerg] 25269#0: open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Permissions errors i can handle but, the NOT-FOUND on php-fpm is beyond me...
I can change the call from php-fpm to "php5-fpm" and run start foreman as ROOT and all the errors go away. But, it will not server php pages. RC=403 on any .php.

do i need to symlink something?

php-fmp package does not exist for ubuntu. Its "php5-fpm".

what do i do now?

composer.json & Procfile

```
"require": {
"heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "v12"
}
```

web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `alias php-fpm=php5-fpm` should fix that.

By the way, `heroku/heroku-buildpack-php` isn't allowed as a dependency in `require` (Heroku will reject it on push); put it in `require-dev`. For local dev, you should usually run without `--no-dev`.

As `v12` wouldn't track buildpack updates, `dev_master` is probably also a better version constraint for the time being, just to make sure you receive the latest version of the package (and one that mirrors what you get on Heroku).

Today's update (tagged v13; I guess you see the problem already :)) also includes a bunch of updates to Nginx config defaults; give those a try.

Comment: i ended up removing all the composer and all the foreman stuff from the project and then using "heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php" before pushing the project.  seems to work now but Heroku's nginx 1.4.6 is not responding to http hdr "Expect: 100-continue" on a GET...